# Is it possible to use the ScalaTest BDD syntax in a JUnit environment?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I would like to describe tests in BDD style e.g. with FlatSpec but keep JUnit as a test runner.

The ScalaTest Quick Start does not seem to show any example of this:

http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_junit_4

I first tried naively to write tests within `@Test` methods, but that doesn't work and the assertion is never tested:

```
@Test def foobarBDDStyle {
    "The first name control" must "be valid" in {
        assert(isValid("name·1"))
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this? It would be even better if regular tests can be mixed and matched with BDD-style tests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way you probably want to do that is to use the @RunWith annotation, like this:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
 class MySuite extends FlatSpec {
   "The first name control" must "be valid" in {
        assert(isValid("name·1"))
    }
 }
```

JUnit 4 will use ScalaTest's JUnitRunner to run the FlatSpec as a JUnit test suite.

Comment: Is it possible to run all ScalaTests with JUnitRunner by default? The reason: we'd like to run tests from Gradle, and apparently, JUnitRunner provides better integration capabilities.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to have `def`s and `@Test` annotations. Here is an example:

```
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.junit.ShouldMatchersForJUnit

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class SpelHelperSpec extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchersForJUnit {

  "SpelHelper" should "register and evaluate functions " in {
    new SpelHelper()
      .registerFunctionsFromClass(classOf[Functions])
      .evalExpression(
        "#test('check')", new {}, classOf[String]) should equal ("check")
  }

  it should "not register non public methods " in {
    val spelHelper = new SpelHelper()
      .registerFunctionsFromClass(classOf[Functions])
    evaluating { spelHelper.evalExpression("#testNonPublic('check')",
      new {}, classOf[String]) } should produce [SpelEvaluationException]
  }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/abhin4v/spelhelper/blob/master/src/test/scala/net/abhinavsarkar/spelhelper/SpelHelperSpec.scala)